# Adding a row in one pandas dataframe to a row in another (summating)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of dataframes. Each of these have around 30 rows in them. I am making a new dataframe, each row in the new dataframe I wish to be the sum of all of the rows with indexes starting with `Tc` plus the row with an index which says `Ru-097`. I am currently taking the sum of the rows with indexes starting with `Tc` using the code below:

```
for i in df_dict: 
    xs_elem.loc[i] = df_dict[i][df_dict[i].index.str.startswith(inta)].sum(axis=0, skipna = True)
```

Where `df_dict` is the original dictionary of dataframes and `xs_elem` is the new dataframe. I am currently struggling to workout how to now add the row from each original dataframe with the index `Ru-097`. I have attached an example of one of the dataframes in the original dictionary:

```
    {'093Nb-a':              0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0  ...  \
 product                                                        ...   
 Mo-093       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Mo-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Mo-093(L16)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Mo-094       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Mo-095       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Mo-096       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-091(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-091(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-092       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-092(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-092(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Nb-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-095       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-095(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-095(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-096(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   
 Tc-096(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   

                    35.5        36.0        36.5       37.0       37.5  \
 product                                                                 
 Mo-093        10.040000   14.632800   21.599300   32.06920   49.24130   
 Mo-093(L00)    9.744110   13.460200   17.185100   20.28300   27.32540   
 Mo-093(L16)    0.295912    1.172700    4.414180   11.78630   21.91600   
 Mo-094       196.562000  204.674000  210.715000  217.95200  224.37300   
 Mo-095        57.097900   54.979600   50.882000   49.70360   46.20760   
 Mo-096         3.978270    3.847120    3.752030    3.71361    3.63636   
 Nb-091(L00)   52.024500   53.725600   57.453200   57.88070   60.03960   
 Nb-091(L01)   17.239500   18.107100   20.356500   20.97550   21.67950   
 Nb-092        82.068500   82.352600   81.429500   78.72100   77.60420   
 Nb-092(L00)   58.983100   59.228600   58.089800   55.80080   54.81690   
 Nb-092(L01)   23.085400   23.124000   23.339800   22.92020   22.78720   
 Nb-093(L00)   40.232200   39.298800   39.472100   37.60480   37.53590   
 Nb-093(L01)    6.356590    6.371910    6.408030    5.82185    5.75791   
 Nb-094(L00)    0.933374    0.947151    1.165000    1.19548    1.42785   
 Nb-094(L01)    1.489570    1.385020    1.737430    1.63560    1.96983   
 Tc-093(L00)    3.000230    8.628490   17.486900   31.77190   46.47390   
 Tc-093(L01)    0.063022    0.201900    0.431364    1.14585    2.91240   
 Tc-094(L00)  895.490000  907.463000  916.315000  916.49400  902.47600   
 Tc-094(L01)   24.440700   23.595100   22.438600   20.92200   19.39410   
 Tc-095       172.828000  152.575000  129.593000  111.87600   96.75620   
 Tc-095(L00)  165.202000  145.326000  122.658000  105.17800   90.25420   
 Tc-095(L01)    7.625800    7.249500    6.934840    6.69773    6.50196   
 Tc-096(L00)    5.884210    5.643140    5.484500    5.34090    5.19044   
 Tc-096(L01)    1.794880    1.750060    1.739150    1.71570    1.70735   

                   38.0       38.5       39.0       39.5       40.0  
 product                                                             
 Mo-093        63.57020   89.75830  111.03700  145.84000  166.05700  
 Mo-093(L00)   29.22050   37.55490   39.94700   49.35280   52.41390  
 Mo-093(L16)   34.34970   52.20340   71.09020   96.48730  113.64400  
 Mo-094       228.25400  234.06500  239.76000  238.56400  236.34500  
 Mo-095        43.55800   42.00010   39.56730   38.08940   36.88660  
 Mo-096         3.49909    3.35616    3.29289    3.12873    3.01025  
 Nb-091(L00)   61.46730   64.53930   66.55750   69.13940   71.44250  
 Nb-091(L01)   22.83200   24.30250   25.53310   26.91970   28.45680  
 Nb-092        73.17120   72.87840   69.16360   68.70760   64.55220  
 Nb-092(L00)   51.50720   51.10550   48.53910   48.01630   44.93510  
 Nb-092(L01)   21.66400   21.77290   20.62450   20.69130   19.61710  
 Nb-093(L00)   36.25430   36.29230   35.42060   35.73530   35.10910  
 Nb-093(L01)    5.53577    5.55193    5.39226    5.42066    5.29100  
 Nb-094(L00)    1.45868    1.66030    1.72756    1.92365    2.05499  
 Nb-094(L01)    1.81729    2.10282    2.05614    2.29654    2.29348  
 Tc-093(L00)   75.29960   93.79430  131.43600  155.85000  198.16200  
 Tc-093(L01)    6.56885    9.81136   15.80680   21.01230   29.64780  
 Tc-094(L00)  877.68600  834.88300  783.80600  732.76100  676.82000  
 Tc-094(L01)   17.99270   16.90750   15.47530   14.18860   12.92230  
 Tc-095        86.07090   80.83800   73.93850   66.92640   63.73640  
 Tc-095(L00)   79.79190   74.78590   67.91930   61.08270   58.06560  
 Tc-095(L01)    6.27897    6.05212    6.01928    5.84365    5.67085  
 Tc-096(L00)    5.08840    4.81673    4.46807    4.29650    4.09283  
 Tc-096(L01)    1.68199    1.52316    1.35884    1.33841    1.29647  

 [24 rows x 80 columns],
 '096Mo-p':              0.5  1.0           1.5       2.0           2.5       3.0  \
 product                                                                 
 Mo-092       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Mo-093       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Mo-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Mo-093(L16)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Mo-094       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Mo-095       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Mo-096       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.001947   
 Nb-090       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-090(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-090(L02)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-091(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-091(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-092       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-092(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-092(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  3.795890e-09  0.000014   
 Nb-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  4.981000e-07  0.000046   
 Nb-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-095       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Nb-095(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-095       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-095(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-095(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-096(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-096(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Tc-097(L00)  0.0  0.0  1.475680e-09  0.002265  3.413350e-02  0.220070   
 Zr-090       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   
 Zr-091       0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   

                   3.5       4.0        4.5        5.0  ...        35.5  \
 product                                                ...               
 Mo-092       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    0.194698   
 Mo-093       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   81.630300   
 Mo-093(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   74.056400   
 Mo-093(L16)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    7.573870   
 Mo-094       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...  261.417000   
 Mo-095       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...  221.953000   
 Mo-096       0.051812  0.062333   0.038230   0.125293  ...  107.862000   
 Nb-090       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    0.122764   
 Nb-090(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    0.093987   
 Nb-090(L02)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    0.028778   
 Nb-091(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   27.828200   
 Nb-091(L01)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   10.945500   
 Nb-092       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   11.128200   
 Nb-092(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    7.450080   
 Nb-092(L01)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    3.678110   
 Nb-093(L00)  0.000258  0.000301   0.000112   0.000574  ...    3.921400   
 Nb-093(L01)  0.000761  0.000949   0.000442   0.001563  ...    0.858452   
 Nb-094(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    2.803280   
 Nb-094(L01)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    3.109510   
 Nb-095       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    5.090490   
 Nb-095(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    4.780890   
 Tc-093(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...  170.967000   
 Tc-093(L01)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   17.761100   
 Tc-094(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...  272.981000   
 Tc-094(L01)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   24.393900   
 Tc-095       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...  116.815000   
 Tc-095(L00)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...  101.107000   
 Tc-095(L01)  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   15.708100   
 Tc-096(L00)  0.000000  3.516110  10.682500  23.264000  ...   22.490200   
 Tc-096(L01)  0.000000  4.191410  12.629300  27.733700  ...    8.400500   
 Tc-097(L00)  0.835016  0.192408   0.042151   0.054529  ...    0.252571   
 Zr-090       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    1.376020   
 Zr-091       0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...    0.756446   

                    36.0        36.5        37.0        37.5        38.0  \
 product                                                                   
 Mo-092         0.272634    0.364946    0.489507    0.713059    1.102390   
 Mo-093        98.401900  103.999000  119.331000  132.559000  142.175000   
 Mo-093(L00)   88.816300   93.446700  105.037000  115.843000  123.103000   
 Mo-093(L16)    9.585520   10.552800   14.293500   16.715700   19.072500   
 Mo-094       259.271000  259.456000  257.227000  254.758000  252.432000   
 Mo-095       221.619000  219.479000  220.937000  220.069000  221.639000   
 Mo-096       106.605000  106.636000  105.159000  104.590000  103.227000   
 Nb-090         0.200268    0.416199    0.837886    1.364180    1.957160   
 Nb-090(L00)    0.153469    0.345417    0.656147    1.043450    1.479270   
 Nb-090(L02)    0.046800    0.070782    0.181739    0.320725    0.477894   
 Nb-091(L00)   27.835600   27.695900   27.439700   27.346600   26.838200   
 Nb-091(L01)   10.998500   10.923500   10.819500   10.656100   10.467700   
 Nb-092        10.675500   10.260700    9.947860    9.268650    9.021180   
 Nb-092(L00)    7.127640    6.860240    6.659290    6.258230    6.148420   
 Nb-092(L01)    3.547840    3.400410    3.288570    3.010420    2.872750   
 Nb-093(L00)    4.216350    4.472430    4.807140    5.332180    5.787620   
 Nb-093(L01)    0.911584    0.981007    1.036370    1.092960    1.275550   
 Nb-094(L00)    3.025280    3.228980    3.434280    3.544840    3.657970   
 Nb-094(L01)    3.342570    3.523070    3.667980    3.720940    3.648950   
 Nb-095         5.396300    5.733150    6.187680    6.540620    6.927770   
 Nb-095(L00)    5.070740    5.390850    5.818430    6.150300    6.514400   
 Tc-093(L00)  179.691000  201.655000  207.974000  216.272000  226.337000   
 Tc-093(L01)   20.473700   22.198000   23.382300   25.810400   26.247200   
 Tc-094(L00)  253.503000  229.945000  211.226000  193.080000  175.816000   
 Tc-094(L01)   22.306800   20.196000   18.292900   16.571900   15.024400   
 Tc-095       112.903000  110.202000  108.205000  106.184000  104.493000   
 Tc-095(L00)   97.671800   95.428500   93.816100   92.163800   90.759900   
 Tc-095(L01)   15.230800   14.773600   14.388500   14.020400   13.733300   
 Tc-096(L00)   22.006100   21.458900   21.383600   21.027100   20.890300   
 Tc-096(L01)    8.251280    8.073800    8.105300    7.983600    8.019030   
 Tc-097(L00)    0.237078    0.234648    0.227061    0.223095    0.222145   
 Zr-090         1.842150    2.396170    2.952780    3.580560    4.283480   
 Zr-091         0.819205    0.882182    0.937785    0.988787    1.029840   

                    38.5        39.0        39.5        40.0  
 product                                                      
 Mo-092         1.760360    2.767710    4.212900    6.472470  
 Mo-093       156.465000  170.650000  179.715000  192.436000  
 Mo-093(L00)  134.558000  147.327000  154.414000  163.208000  
 Mo-093(L16)   21.907100   23.322400   25.300900   29.228800  
 Mo-094       251.026000  245.157000  243.405000  241.537000  
 Mo-095       220.090000  221.075000  218.101000  218.373000  
 Mo-096       102.861000  101.640000  101.468000  100.550000  
 Nb-090         2.652820    3.936520    5.671160    7.386630  
 Nb-090(L00)    2.001980    3.091590    4.411210    5.615940  
 Nb-090(L02)    0.650844    0.844928    1.259950    1.770700  
 Nb-091(L00)   26.147500   25.086300   23.985700   22.924400  
 Nb-091(L01)   10.252800    9.879630    9.569140    9.279330  
 Nb-092         8.776360    8.634510    8.381030    8.212600  
 Nb-092(L00)    6.015780    5.877360    5.674670    5.522580  
 Nb-092(L01)    2.760590    2.757150    2.706360    2.690020  
 Nb-093(L00)    6.279160    6.786630    7.268600    7.773980  
 Nb-093(L01)    1.356610    1.417320    1.480530    1.550450  
 Nb-094(L00)    3.768570    3.925200    4.158320    4.287010  
 Nb-094(L01)    3.777560    3.852390    4.174570    4.291710  
 Nb-095         7.411410    7.694960    7.853290    8.242470  
 Nb-095(L00)    6.969100    7.230100    7.382570    7.753150  
 Tc-093(L00)  228.672000  230.117000  236.613000  233.893000  
 Tc-093(L01)   26.800900   27.833400   27.689600   27.083300  
 Tc-094(L00)  164.440000  154.054000  142.644000  133.287000  
 Tc-094(L01)   13.786100   13.334300   12.529800   11.707600  
 Tc-095       100.435000   97.116500   95.291700   95.238100  
 Tc-095(L00)   86.978500   84.041900   82.558000   82.254100  
 Tc-095(L01)   13.456400   13.074600   12.733700   12.984000  
 Tc-096(L00)   20.691900   20.669100   19.987400   18.763300  
 Tc-096(L01)    7.911620    7.935570    7.660140    6.969670  
 Tc-097(L00)    0.225346    0.219301    0.214906    0.213265  
 Zr-090         5.082860    5.704280    5.924980    6.033510  
 Zr-091         1.068270    1.093200    1.122820    1.142350
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find rows meeting your criteria in a **single** DataFrame (*df*), you can write:

```
df.query('index == "Ru-097" or index.str.startswith("Tc-")')
```

To sum up these rows, run:

```
df.query('index == "Ru-097" or index.str.startswith("Tc-")')\
    .sum(axis=0, skipna=True)
```

So the whole loop can take the form something like this:

```
for i in df_dict:
    df = df_dict[i]
    xs_elem.loc[i] = df.query('index == "Ru-097" or index.str.startswith("Tc-")')\
        .sum(axis=0, skipna=True)
```

Or even shorter:

```
for i, df in df_dict.items():
    xs_elem.loc[i] = df.query('index == "Ru-097" or index.str.startswith("Tc-")')\
        .sum(axis=0, skipna=True)
```

## Edit following your question

To test my code again, I created the following DataFrame:

```
                 38.0      38.5
product                        
Mo-093        63.5702   89.7583
Ru-097        29.2205   37.5549
Ru-099        34.0007   52.0004
Tc-094(L00)  877.6860  834.8830
Tc-094(L01)   17.9927   16.9075
Tc-095        86.0709   80.8380
```

The first test was how works `df.query` alone and I got:

```
                 38.0      38.5
product                        
Ru-097        29.2205   37.5549
Tc-094(L00)  877.6860  834.8830
Tc-094(L01)   17.9927   16.9075
Tc-095        86.0709   80.8380
```

Then I tested the whole instruction:

```
df.query('index == "Ru-097" or index.str.startswith("Tc-")')\
    .sum(axis=0, skipna=True)
```

getting:

```
38.0    1010.9701
38.5     970.1834
dtype: float64
```

So the part of my code **extracting** the required data from a **single** DataFrame runs OK.
Execute just the above code, for a single source DataFrame, to confirm that
it works OK in your environment.

Probably the source of error is how you attempt to "collect" data
found by `df.query(...).sum(...)` in each turn of the loop:

```
for i in df_dict:
    df = df_dict[i]
    xs_elem.loc[i] = ...
```

Look at the last row of the above loop:

- `xs_elem.loc[i]` returns (probably) a **single** element of a *Series*,
  with index == `i`,
- you attempt to save there another *Series* (the result of
  *df.query(...).sum(...)*).

Initially I concentrated on how to get result from just a single DataFrame,
not looking at how / where you attempt to save it.

Now I see it is a weird construction, leading to an error.

**How you should collect the data (my proposal)**

Instead of your loop, run:

```
xs_elem = pd.DataFrame([ df.query(
    'index == "Ru-097" or index.str.startswith("Tc-")')\
    .sum(axis=0, skipna=True).rename(key)
    for key, df in df_dict.items() ])
```

Details:

1. Start reading from `for key, df in df_dict.items()`, it is the loop
   controlling the enclosing list comprehension.
   *key* contains the dictionary key and *df* - the source dataFrame.
2. `df.query(...).sum(...)` generates a *Series* - data from the current
   DataFrame.
3. Note `.rename(key)` added. It sets the name of this *Series*,
   which then will be the key of a row resulting from this *Series*.
4. The whole list comprehension is the source of the result DataFrame.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: For some reason when running this code, if I run "index == 'Ru-097" it works fine, however when running with index.str.startswith("Tc-")' I get an error: 'TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed'. Do you know why this may be? Thanks